# How does RAID 5 handle unrecoverable sectors on a HDD

Tags: partitioning, raid5

I'm going to set up a RAID 5 on 4 hard drives on my ubuntu system. I plan to use ext4 on a logic volume.

Suppose one disk reports an unrecoverable sector. How would RAID 5 handle this? My understanding is that if the system were to read a file that was partially lost on one disk, the RAID 5 would rebuild it on a different sector on that affected disk.

So my question is; is this true and also is there such a command (maybe `fsck`) that would scan the whole disk and rebuild any unrecoverable sectors.

Comment: I don't know. But I would advice you to look into ZFS RaidZ, since I believe this is more resilient than traditional raid5.

Comment: I thought about using ZFS but since it isn't as fast as ext4 and I have (at least) 2 SMR disks, I thought it best not to use it. As far as I know using ZFS with SMR disks is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: You're right. IMO, SMR disks are generally a bad idea overall. But you're right it's probably more unstable on ZFS.